# PHP convert string time to second

Tags: php, php-carbon

In our `mikrotik` when we get user uptime, that's return a string such as `"2d13m30s"` and i should convert it to second, this stirng can be `"13m30s"` or `"30s"`, i tired to convert it to second but i think there isn't standard php for that

i think in `php` this function as `strtotime` can't be help me to convert it to second and this code what i tested and `gmdate` can convert second to time:

```php
date("s",strtotime("2h2m30s"))
```

Comment: strtotime and date are not really suitable to begin with, if you want to works with times only, without any date portion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see as per the question tags that you have Carbon installed so `CarbonInterval` already handles that for you:

```
echo \Carbon\CarbonInterval::fromstring('2h2m30s') . "\n";
echo \Carbon\CarbonInterval::fromstring('2h2m30s')->totalSeconds . "\n";
```

Output:

```
2 hours 2 minutes 30 seconds
7350
```

Answer (score 2):

`strtotime` understands relative dates, but its units are a bit more verbose than just single letters. Simply replace like so:

```
$strtotime_input = strtr('5d3h20s', [
  'w' => ' week ',
  'd' => ' day ', 
  'h' => ' hour ', 
  'm' => ' minute ', 
  's' => ' second '
]) . ' ago';
```

Now strings such as `5d3h20s` will turn into `5 day 3 hour 20 second ago`. Feed that into `strtotime()`:

```
$timestamp = strtotime($strtotime_input);
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp);

// Or if you need the number of seconds:

echo time() - $timestamp;
```

Comment: Nice and tidy solution!

Answer (score 1):

You can parse it with Regex, too:

`/(?:(?<days>\d+)d)?(?:(?<minutes>\d+)m)?(?:(?<seconds>\d+)s)/`[1](https://regex101.com/r/2v5eyD/1)

```php
$interval = '987d6m5s';
preg_match('/(?:(?<days>\d+)d)?(?:(?<minutes>\d+)m)?(?:(?<seconds>\d+)s)/', $interval, $matches);

$days = $matches['days'] ?: 0;
$minutes = $matches['mins'] ?: 0;
$seconds = $matches['seconds'] ?: 0;

$intervalInSeconds = $days * 24 + $mins * 60 + $seconds;
```

[Live example](https://onlinephp.io?s=fZBdC8IgFIavG-w_nIuBWkFjfUDrw-t-Q0WMaWuQNtQFEf33tFktiMG5OD4-57zoklanKgyOtcxNeZFQcLORhqtrdsbaqFIWEJUekBRsC_cw6FWKFweRmfyE0QjTFNMly256vWMDwghtiChlbXgDxRtqnl8ka6AmIzT87rftayXXZGEzbEVuKaw-fIscQHugKcTOiXzGj-NZW_OpP5pnLc2W4qZWEprgPiQTGMAnpA-z2J39pB15hEEYXDN1YLWocPvz0FQj4t7x_3Yei24hEeO4W5hNWfLe8gQ%2C&v=8.1.9)

Any `date` and similar functions does not work nicely with interval of seconds and not timestamp of seconds.

Comment: As my answer your doesn't work with '2m30s'

Comment: @SimoneRossaini Yes it does

Comment: You have change the snippet :)

Comment: I like your approach. **I would just add optional hours**. I could imagine something like `2d4h45m33s`. Also, I would use the `i` regex pattern option to make it case insensitive.

Comment: Also put the seconds as optional because we don't know if `0s` could be ommited if we have something like `1d` only. [Tests done here on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/EwLM2D/1)

Comment: @PatrickJanser From what OP has provided (3 exapmles) there is always seconds part and never hours part. Also always lowercase letter.

Comment: @Justinas: I would not assume that OP always thinks of all the cases. Neither of these improvements are complicated or dangerous. We could even imagine weeks or months could be in the string. My comments were intended to be constructive improvements, not criticisms. I would have posted my own complete solution if it would have been the case.